# Make a circle shaped LeafLet map

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, leaflet

Im building a webpage using [Boostrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) and want to make a [LeafLet](http://leafletjs.com/) map that sits alongside some [Boostrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) `img-circle`'s. I tried applying the `img-circle`class to the `map-preview` but it seems like [LeafLet](http://leafletjs.com/) just draws **over** the circle. I also tried to apply `border-radius:50%` with no effect.

Map html:

```
 <div class="map-wrapper">
     <div id="map-preview" class=" img-circle"></div>
 </div>
```

Map css:

```
.map-wrapper{
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    display: inline-block;
}

.map-wrapper #map-preview{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
```

JavaScript to load the map:

```
var map = L.map('map-preview').setView([48.46477, 7.88112], 15);
mapLink = '<a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a>';
L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {attribution: '&copy; ' + mapLink + ' Contributors', maxZoom: 18,}).addTo(map);
var marker = L.marker([48.46477, 7.88112]).addTo(map);
map.scrollWheelZoom.disable();
```

What I get:
[image: Result]

What I want (I would have to move the zoom buttons down, but i guess that should be no problem):
[image: Desired]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should also set a `z-index` property to the map container:

```
#mapid{
  width: 400px; 
  height: 400px; 
  border-radius: 200px; 
  position: relative; 
  z-index: 500
}
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/Gje2ndRFdKwubWgCsHXW?p=preview

Comment: Thank you :), btw how did you disable the zoom buttons?

Comment: Glad to help you. They are not disabled, they are hidden due to `border-radius`

Comment: Yes I realized it myself after some playing around with it

Comment: Quite old post, but if some other people came across and want to know how to disable zoom buttons: just set `zoomControl: false` in map options :)

Answer (score 0):

Your mistake is in your CSS ...

You have to set a dimension to your map (square in pixels) and set your radius to half of this value.

For example

```
width: 400px;
height: 400px;
border-radius: 200px;
```

See http://plnkr.co/edit/jwpVbNqgk6V9xiZepHs5?p=preview

Note: this does not seem to work on all browsers

Comment: I tried it in both my `map-wrapper` and `map-preview` but none of both did work, the map still draws over the circle

Comment: Can you give a link to what you are trying to achieve (or an example on plnkr.co) to illustrate ?

Comment: I added two images. I hope its enough to understand what I want :)

Comment: The plunker I proposed does NOT work on Chrome and Safari ... You can see a circle and immediately after the square is back.